# Exchange mobile sync has been disabled using gmail

Tags: gmail, exchange, active-sync

My Exchange mobile sync has been disabled twice already by the exchange server. The reason is that the corporate policy is to disable mobile sync when a connection is attempted from a different device id. I checked and the reason is that for some reason at certain times Android sends Device ID: 0 instead of the real one.

I am using Lollipop, latest exchange services (Nov 2014) and Gmail as a client.